# Visual Basic 2008: Textbox or label for displaying an answer?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

What is the advantage of using a text box to display an answer in Visual Basic versus a label?

Comment: This has to be a homework question.  You would know the advantage if you used it in your own project and had chosen the proper control for the job you needed it to do.  Don't hesitate to try, it is just point-and-click in the Winforms designer.

Answer (score 0):

Using a (non-Disabled) textbox allows the user to select and copy the text.

Comment: not-disabled, Yes. But it should be read-only to mimic the label closely.

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically trigger a new event as soon as the textbox's text is changed using the textChanged function. this is not possible in case of a label.

Comment: If he wants it to be editable, then (I hope) he wouldn't ask the question.

Comment: `Label` also has a `TextChanged` event.  (It's inherited from `Control`)